# How can I use my fine-tuned model through openai's API?

Tags: gpt

I have read the docs extensively and cannot find how to specify that I want to use my fine-tuned model and not one of their pretrained models for my completion job.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: Do you want to fine-tune a model from an existing one but you don't find any?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to open-ai's playground and then click view code. There you will have sample api requests with your fine-tuned model name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).